# insert first data into a recursive sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following table:

```
Create Table if not exists Categories(
    category_id int (10) primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    category_name varchar (20) NOT NULL,
    parent_category_id int (10) NOT NULL,   
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_category_id) REFERENCES Categories(category_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

The table is holding every category I have on my site - and each category have a parent category (for example 'computer' is the parent category of 'programming')
I have a few top categories which don't have any parent category => parent_category_id =0

My question is how to insert the data for the top categories.
when i'm trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO  `databaseproject`.`categories` (`category_id` ,`category_name` ,`parent_category_id`)
VALUES (NULL ,  'computers',  '0')
```

I'm getting the error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`databaseproject`.`categories`, CONSTRAINT `categories_ibfk_1` 
FOREIGN KEY (`parent_category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`category_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

what can I do to insert those categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make parent_category_id nullable, and parent categories have a null parent_category_id, or add a root row with id 0.

Comment: I would advocate to use `NULL` instead of a "magic" number (and the root row would need to have the `parent_category_id = NULL` anyway)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Agreed on preferring NULL, but on occasion there's a bizarro software architect who insists on having no NULLs anywhere... I know at least one such person. :-) The root node can have (category_id, parent_category_id) = (0, 0).

Comment: I can understand the architect - nulls effect usage of indexes (nulls are not indexes so indexes cannot be used). in DWH sytems - only magic numbers (as @a_horse_with_no_name calls them).

Comment: @haki: horse and I are Postgres junkies. In our ghetto, nulls are indexed just fine in btree indexes. Else yeah... my father's ghetto is SQL-Server, where I seem to remember that nulls are not indexed indeed at some point (and maybe still aren't).

Comment: @Denis: I wasn't actually thinking about indexing at all, only about properly representing this kind of data.

Comment: Thank you all, making it nullable solved the problem, just for general knowledge how can I add a root row?

Comment: @ShaiZarzewski: something like `insert into tablename(id, parent_id) values (0, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  First, category_id is an auto_increment field, meaning the database will create a value for you when you insert a new row, so you don't need to provide it.  You certainly can't set it to null, since you have specifically said it can't be null, which is absolutely what you want for an auto-incrementing id field.  Just change your insert to:

```
INSERT INTO  'databaseproject'.'categories' ('category_name' ,'parent_category_id')
VALUES ('computers',  '0')
```

But you still have another problem.  parent_category_id has to refer to a valid record in the categories table because of the constraint you created.  You can solve this problem by allowing the field to be null (get rid of the "NOT NULL" when creating the parent_category_id), and using null instead of zero to indicate this is a top level record.